# Creating valid XHTML when using jQuery .append()

Tags: jquery, xhtml, append

In the examples here:  http://api.jquery.com/append/  they show straight HTML being used as an argument:

```
$('.inner').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

But the validator at W3 will object to this like so

```
Line 96, column 76: document type does not allow element "p" here
…ata).append("<p class='pag
```

How should I do this to get valid XHTML?

EDIT - Here is an example of what is written by PHP:

```
$('#citations_18401-01').html(data).append("<p class='paginated_link'><b>Result Pages:</b>&nbsp;<b class='paginated_link'>1</b>&nbsp;<a class='paginated_link' href='property_info.php?lot=18401-01&quote_set=1&limit=30&tab=3'>2</a>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>");
```

Comment: Is this inside a `<script>` tag?

Comment: The W3C validator would never see what Javascript produces because it doesn't run JS.

Comment: what do the elements with class="inner" look like?

Comment: .inner is from the example at jQuery.

Comment: The validator is seeing the AJAX call with HTML as an argument to append()

Comment: @Dennis - yes it is inside <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap your inline jQuery with special tags for XHTML. See [this article](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm).