# Issue in adding html tags to .append() jquery .xhtml

Tags: jquery

I have the following script in xhtml. I am using prime faces 3.1.

```
<script>            
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#form_Detail").submit(function(){
                    $('input[name$="vInputTxt1"]').each(function(){
                        if($(this).val()==""){
                            $("#errorMessages").append("v is required");
                            $("#errorMessages").append('<br />');
                        }
                    });

                    $('input[name$="gcInputTxt"]').each(function(){
                        if($(this).val()==""){
                    Line A:     $("#errorMessages").append("gc  is required");
                        }
                    });
            });
        }); 
    <script>
```

Everything works fine till I include

```
$("#errorMessages").append('<br />');
```

After adding br tag,I get the error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; on Line A.

Probably because the html which is getting generated is :

```
$('input[name$="vInputTxt1"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){
       $("#errorMessages").append("v  is required");
       $("#errorMessages").append('<br />');
    }
});

                           $('input[name$=&quot;gcInputTxt&quot;]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==&quot;&quot;){
     $(&quot;#errorMessages&quot;).append(&quot;gc  is required&quot;);
    }
```

});

Please notice that evry `""` after br tag has got converted to `&quot;`

Being new to jquery & xhtml, I am not able to understand the reason. I did read [Why can't I add a <br /> with JQuery .html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173556/why-cant-i-add-a-br-with-jquery-html) & [Creating valid XHTML when using jQuery .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166628/creating-valid-xhtml-when-using-jquery-append) , but couldn't identify the issue.

If I do not use, $("#errorMessages").append('
'); the html does gets appended to the div errorMessages.

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: What happens if you do not include the <br/> tag?
If you can show some for your html code?

Comment: @Digvijay Yes, The the html code does get added to the div in that case.

Comment: That means no errors if you do not append the <br/> tag?

Comment: @Digvijay yes, evrything works fine till <br/> is included.

Comment: Then my be you can try <br> instead of <br/>.

Comment: Have tried all permutaions & combinations of br..

Comment: have alredy written in the question above

Comment: [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9126/discussion-between-digvijay-yadav-and-shikha-dhawan)

Answer (score 0):

Here I In the statement before you append 
 tag you have the following statement

```
$("#errorMessages").append("v  is required");
```

This append method of jquery is for appending some html element to the page, but you are appending a string that jquery cannot parse. So it gives the error of unexpected token.

Comment: `çode`$("#errorMessages").append("v  is required");`çode` works perfectly fine & gets displayed correctly if I do not include `çode`$("#errorMessages").append('<br />');`çode`

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you change the line to:
    `$("#errorMessages").append("<br />");`

If not, change the 
    `.append("v  is required");` to `.html("v  is required");` and 
    `.append("gc  is required");` to `.html("gc  is required");`

Comment: Have tried both : using $("#errorMessages").append("<br />"); & changing .append to .html. But,still the problem remains.